# Opening IE explorere with Selenium in python 35 gives weird error

Tags: python, internet-explorer, selenium

After correcting zoom level IE now opens python.org but I still get lots of errors'

```
from selenium import webdriver

Scripts\\drivers\\IEDriverServer.exe")
driver = webdriver.Ie()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")

assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

I get these errors in python:

> > > > > > > > > > > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > > > > > > > > > >                           File "", line 1, in 
> > > > > > > > > > > >                         AssertionError
> > > > > > > > > > > >                         Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > > > > > > > > > >                           File "", line 1, in 
> > > > > > > > > > > >                           File "C:\Users\g14988\Documents\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 365, in find_element_by_name
> > > > > > > > > > > >                             return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)
> > > > > > > > > > > >                           File "C:\Users\g14988\Documents\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 752, in find_element
> > > > > > > > > > > >                             'value': value})['value']
> > > > > > > > > > > >                           File "C:\Users\g14988\Documents\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
> > > > > > > > > > > >                             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
> > > > > > > > > > > >                           File "C:\Users\g14988\Documents\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
> > > > > > > > > > > >                             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
> > > > > > > > > > > >                         selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to find element with name == q
> > >
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       NameError: name 'elem' is not defined
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       NameError: name 'elem' is not defined
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       NameError: name 'elem' is not defined
> > >
> > > > > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > > > >               File "", line 1, in 
> > > > > >               File "C:\Users\g14988\Documents\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 510, in close
> > > > > >                 self.execute(Command.CLOSE)
> > > > > >               File "C:\Users\g14988\Documents\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
> > > > > >                 self.error_handler.check_response(response)
> > > > > >               File "C:\Users\g14988\Documents\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
> > > > > >                 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
> > > > > >             selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: Unable to get browser

Comment: I think that find element by name not find anything. Therefore exception was thrown

Answer (score 2):

you can see in the exception:

Browser zoom level was set to 112%. It should be set to 100%

set the zoom to 100%

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-zoom-level-in-internet-explorer

Comment: Thanks...that solved it :)

Comment: Plz marked it as correct answer

Comment: It only helped for 2 seconds, but first hurdle down.....

Comment: It just gave a new bunch of errors.

Comment: question updated with new info..